# Class public instance fields

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, properties

Can anybody explain, why subclass public instance fields cannot be just set over parent props before parent constructor (both are known during instantiation)? Ofc you could then override public fields by parent constructor, but it is clearer to me than setting it once before constructor and then for children after super(). Is there some language obstacle?

When this proposal came, I expected that it was the purpose of whole thing (simply declared before constructor).

Let's say, I got base class with constructor which is the same for all subclasses. Because constructor can take arguments, in some cases, I want to initialize classes as simple as possible like `new MyClass(args)`

```
class Person {
  // public fields initialized before constructor
  age
  gender
  etc
     
  constructor(input) {
    setProps() // empty
    parse(input)
  }
  
  setProps() {}

  parse() {
    // get age, gender, etc
  }
}

new Person(input) // works
```

For subclasses, the old school js way was either to rewrite constructor with super() followed by subclass part or to call method like `setProps()` (both seems to me just like coding overhead)

```
class Student extends Person {
  setProps() {
    this.lessons = []
  }

  parse(input) {
    super.parse.call(this, input);
    input.forEach(row => this.lessons.append(row.something))
  }
}

new Student(input) // works
```

With subclass public instance fields, I get this (ofc as [doc](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#public_instance_fields) says)

```
class Student extends Person {
  // public fields initialize after super()
  lessons = []

  parse(input) {
    super.parse.call(this, input);
    input.forEach(row => this.lessons.append(row.something))
  }
}

new Student(input) // throws error because this.lessons is undefined
```

Am I missing some approach not mentioned above?